# How to create a card hover background color

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to set up a card layout where the cards change background color when the user hovers over the card.  Like the cards on this page: https://texasdeafed.org/students/programs

I've tried adding the hover info in the header, where I have the shadow:

```
.card:hover {
    background-color: #fffff
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #DCE1E0;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: #fffff;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <br />
  <center>
    <h1>Family Weekend
      <br />
      <br />Retreat</h1>
  </center>
  <br />

  <img src="/cms/lib6/TX01923182/Centricity/Domain/180/Shelly_Parent_Liaison_ca    rdflipped.jpg" alt="Woman reading Parent Liaison card by     texasdeafed.org" style="width:100%">

  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <p>
      A special weekend in Austin for families with deaf and hard of hearing children hosted by the Educational Resource Center on Deafness at Texas School for the Deaf </p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the hover color to change to white, but there is no change at all.

Comment: Your color code for white is incorrect. Try #fff or #ffffff (3 or 6 characters)

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion, but there was no change.

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onmxyk1s/)

Answer (score 0):

All you doing is working pretty great, Only error your css have is hex code.
Where you are trying to give white color using #fffff - 5 times letter f, It need to be 6 times,
Check my response! 
Good Luck.

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #DCE1E0;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <br />
  <center>
    <h1>Family Weekend
      <br />
      <br />Retreat</h1>
  </center>
  <br />

  <img src="/cms/lib6/TX01923182/Centricity/Domain/180/Shelly_Parent_Liaison_ca    rdflipped.jpg" alt="Woman reading Parent Liaison card by     texasdeafed.org" style="width:100%">

  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <p>
      A special weekend in Austin for families with deaf and hard of hearing children hosted by the Educational Resource Center on Deafness at Texas School for the Deaf </p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set background-color to `#ffffff`.

Comment: Thanks.  Ori Drori suggested the same; it works now.  Thanks to you both!